# How to send an array of objects to server in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I want to send a list of the array to the server but I have troubles on it.

[This is my backend information that I should send data like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/023e0.png)

This is my code:

```
loadRequest(request: "/tripTemporary/", parameters:
                ["startDate":"\(FindDriverViewController.dateToGo)",
                 "startTime":"\(FindDriverViewController.timeTOGo)",
                 "passengerNumber":"\(FindDriverViewController.PasengerCount)",
                 "typeId":"\(ServiceModeViewController.serviceMode)",
                 "originName":"\(MapViewController.sourceCity)",
                 "destinationName":"\(MapViewController.destinationCity)",
                 "passengerId":"\(ViewController.id)",
                    "tripCheckPoints":"{['address':'\(MapViewController.source)','longitude':'\(MapViewController.sourceLng)','latitude':'\(MapViewController.sourceLat)'],['address':'\(MapViewController.destination)','longitude':'\(MapViewController.Destinationlng)','latitude':'\(MapViewController.DestinationLat)']}"

                ],
                        json: true, get: false, callback: { (data) in

                            print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
            }, method: "POST")
```

Please help me.

Comment: Unrelated but replace `NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!` with `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!`. There is no reason to use `NSString` in this case.

Comment: thanks for your suggest. do you have any recommend for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach to be followed is to use the `Encodable`, you'll be able to get the desired JSON string without the need of the tedious manual handling.

First, you should define the struct for the request (and let it conforms to `Encodable`):

```
struct RequestFormat: Encodable {
    var startDate: String
    var startTime: String
    var passengerNumber: String
    var typeId: String
    var originName: String
    var destinationName: String
}
```

then you could directly use it after setting the desired info:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
// dummy values
let myRequestObject = RequestFormat(startDate: "1/1/2018",
                                    startTime: "8:00PM",
                                    passengerNumber: "2",
                                    typeId: "10",
                                    originName: "Origin Name",
                                    destinationName: "Destination Name")
```

hence

```
do {
    let result = try encoder.encode([myRequestObject])
    if let resultString = String(data: result, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(resultString)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

As you can see, the output of logging printing `resultString` would be:

> [{"startTime":"8:00PM","typeId":"10","originName":"Origin
>   Name","startDate":"1/1/2018","destinationName":"Destination
>   Name","passengerNumber":"2"}]

Note that I encoded as an array (`try encoder.encode([myRequestObject])`), if you are aiming to get a *single* object, you could simply implement it as:

```
let result = try encoder.encode(myRequestObject)
```

Also, you could -obviously- add more that just one object to the encoded array:

```
let result = try encoder.encode([myRequestObject, myRequestObject2, myRequestObject3])
```

which `myRequestObject`, `myRequestObject2` and `myRequestObject3` are typed as `RequestFormat`.

Comment: thanks. i do your help and it works. but i don't know how should i POST to server. would you please help me?

Comment: In `loadRequest`, `parameter` is a string, correct? which means that you could pass `resultString` directly to it. What's the part that you are missing?\

Comment: no loadRequest, is [String:Any]. this is the part that i'm missing

Comment: @AmirhosseinKhodaei are you using any third party library? such as Alamofire?

Comment: in case only if we send as array: let result = try encoder.encode([myRequestObject])
, otherwise it should : let result = try encoder.encode(myRequestObject)